# How do I store data from an API to an array in Angular?

Tags: angular, api

I am trying to retrieve data from an API and store it to an array in Angular. I have looked at tutorials and done what they said, but any time I try to log the array to the console (or use it anywhere else) it shows that it is empty (which is what I initialize it as before changing the value). I have tried moving the console.log command to many different places in file to see if that was the issue but it hasn't made any difference. The code from my app.component.ts file is below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api-service.service';
import { User } from 'src/User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'apitable2';
  users: User[] = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onGetUsers()
    console.log(this.users)
  }

  onGetUsers() {
    this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe(
      response => {this.users = response}
    )
  }
  

  
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I should also mention that logging to the console is not the end goal, I should have been more clear. I am trying to pass the array this.users to a child component, but whenever I do so it shows that the array is empty still. So I am looking for a way to pass the array after the function onGetUsers() has completely finished running.

Comment: How are you trying to pass this to a child component..?

Answer (score 0):

You should console.log after the data comes because when you are working with API, these kinds of activities are async, which means a response is not provided immediately after you call function.

```js
  onGetUsers() {
    this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe(
      response => {
           this.users = response
           console.log(this.users);

      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: That worked for the console.log! But now I have the problem that when I try to use the array in a child component it still returns that it is empty. Is this the same issue? And if so how would I tell it to wait for the function to finish before I pass the variable between components?

Comment: Weird! It should work, anyway you can check the users with *ngIf="users?.length" before passing the users

Comment: That still didn't seem to work, and now I can see that the child component isn't running at all after I added the ngIf command. Is it possible I need to return this.users somehow in the function in order for it to actually update? I'm not sure what else the issue would be as it appears like it isn't updating the array at all outside of the function.

Comment: What is the output of console.log in above code?

Comment: It is just the data from the api that I am trying to get. It does exactly what I want it to, but it just isn't letting me pass it on to another component.

Comment: `0: {gender: 'male', name: {…}, location: {…}, email: 'karl.johnson@example.com', login: {…}, …}
1: {gender: 'male', name: {…}, location: {…}, email: 'finn.morris@example.com', login: {…}, …}
2: {gender: 'female', name: {…}, location: {…}, email: 'romane.perez@example.com', login: {…}, …}
3: {gender: 'female', name: {…}, location: {…}, email: 'lucia.hammeren@example.com', login: {…}, …}
4: {gender: 'female', name: {…}, location: {…}, email: 'romane.renaud@example.com', login` This is part of the exact output if that is more helpful, but as I said, it is the data from the api I am using.

Comment: ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes?.users?.currentValue);
  }

Comment: Use above code in the child component

Answer (score 0):

When you call your API, the code inside subscribe() doesn't run until a response is received from the server. Try moving your console.log statement inside the subscribe handler, and you should see the values you're expecting:

```
  onGetUsers() {
    this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.users = response;
        console.log(this.users);
      }
    )
  }
```

In order to understand what is happening here, you really need to understand rxJS observables. The call to getUsers() is returning an observable, which you are subscribing to. Your code continues to run which is why your console.log() call happens before the array has been populated, and it's only when the API has a result for you that the code inside subscribe() runs.

Comment: Yes, this works great when I try to console.log(). However when I try to do anything else with the array this.users (I am trying to pass it to a child component) it still returns as though it is empty in the child component file. Is there a way to wait for the function to finish running before the variable is passed?

Comment: Rather than wait for the result before passing it to the child component, you should make the child component work asynchronously as well. Explaining that is a beyond the scope of a comment though. One simple option might be to use an *ngIf to prevent your child component from being instantiated until there are users in the list. Something like `<ChildComp *ngIf="users.length"></ChildComp>` might work.

Answer (score 0):

If users list should be fetched at the initialization of your app component (it seems to be the case, because you call it inside `OnInit`),
you can simplify your code and use directly `Observable` returned by the HttpClient.

Service `api.service.ts` :

```js
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  ...
  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('...url...');
  }
}
```

Component `app.component.ts` :

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  users$ = this.apiService.getUsers();

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
}
```

Template `app.component.html` :

```html
  <child-cpt [users]="users$ | async"></child-cpt>
```

And if you want to check value returned before displaying your child component, you can do :

```html
  <ng-container *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
    <!-- only if users is defined -->
    <child-cpt [users]="users"></child-cpt>
  </ng-container>
```